# How to protect sub class methods to be accessed from super class type objects

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class Employee{
   public int getSalary(){
      return 500;
   }
}

class Manager extends Employee{
   public int getSalary(){
      return 1000;
   }
   public int getBonus(){
      return 200;
   }
}
```

Below code in the main() method

```
Employee e = new Employee();
Manager m = new Manager();

System.out.println(m.getBonus());
//Below will throw error as Employee does not have a method getBonus()
//System.out.println(e.getBonus());

Employee test = new Manager();
System.out.println(test.getSalary());
```

Below works. Should it work, Just by casting, I'm able to get the bonus method of a     Manager. However, type of test is Employee. Can I protect getBonus method of Manager such that an object of type Employee can't access it even after casting without changing the accessidentifier

```
System.out.println(((Manager)test).getBonus());
```

The output is

```
200
1000
200
```

Comment: Well, if you cast, you no longer have an `Employee` reference... You have a `Manager` reference which obviously would need to have access to its own methods.

Comment: If you want to protect super classes from sub classes, why do you consider inheritance at all?

Comment: In addition, how would this kind of "protection" work? It would require that a superclass would know every single one of its subclasses, which is quite impossible given that you don't know where your code could be used.

Comment: If you want such a "protection" - make the method private and it won't be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `test` points to(or is a reference to) a `Manager` object. 
Every `Manager` object is also an `Employee` Object
Not every `Employee` object need to be `Manager` object.

```
Employee test = new Manager();
```

You are just saying that test (which can point to any Employee object, so it can also point to manager objects) points to the `new Manager()` object created.

So when you use `new Manager()` it is creating a manager object and a reference to that is stored in test(Which is of type Employee), its valid because Manager is also Employee

By casting you are saying that object pointed by `test` is not an ordinary `Employee` but a `Manager`, so casting returns a manager reference and you can invoke methods suitable for managers on that object.

So if you are creating object using `new Manager()` what ever your reference type is it can access all its public methods.